# How to write sql for this logic?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following tables (this is abbreviated)

```
tableAssignments
    id
    timestamp             // updated when row is modified
    tableSystems
    tableUsers
    ...

tableAssignmentsSnapshot
    id
    timestamp             // set when row created, snapshots never change
    tableSystemsSnapshot
    tableUsersSnapshot
    tableAssignments_id   // reference to "tableAssignments" row this was created from
    syncKey               // Changed when snapshots are created, max value is latest
```

Sometime after the tableAssignments are changed, snapshots of all the assignments are taken and the snapshots are created with the same syncKey.  I am trying to write a query to check if the latest "tableAssignmentsSnapshot" are up to date or if new ones should be taken.  The logic required is:

1. Determine the latest tableAssignmentSnapshots for each system, which is determine by maximum syncKey (see query below).
2. Join the result from #1 with tableAssignments.
3. If timestamp from tableAssignments > timestamp from tableAssignmentsSnapshot then new snapshot is required.

The following query accomplishes step #1 and runs fast.  It returns the tableAssignmentSnapshots with the greatest value of "syncKey" for each system.

```
select * from
    tableAssignmentsSnapshot d inner join tableSystemsSnapshot e
    on d.systemId = e.id
    where d.syncKey = (select MAX(syncKey) from tableAssignmentsSnapshot y inner join tableSystemsSnapshot z
  on y.systemId = z.id
   where tableSystems_id = e.tableSystems_id)
```

I'm struggling with what to do next.  I need to be able to do something like the following but am having trouble with the syntax required:

```
select * from tableAssignments a right outer join
(
    the result from above query
)
on a.id = ?.tableAssignments_id
```

Comment: FYI `timestamp` is a horrible column name. It's a reserved word and a data type (which also happens to not have anything at all to do with date/time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your first query on a CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT * -- Here you should list only the columns that you are gonna need
    FROM tableAssignmentsSnapshot D
    INNER JOIN tableSystemsSnapshot E
        ON D.systemId = E.id
    WHERE D.syncKey = ( select MAX(syncKey) from tableAssignmentsSnapshot y inner join tableSystemsSnapshot z
                        on y.systemId = z.id
                        where tableSystems_id = e.tableSystems_id)
)

SELECT * 
FROM tableAssignments A
RIGHT JOIN CTE B
ON A.id = B.tableAssignments_id
```